# Create NSDictionary from another NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` that logs this:

```
    address = "30 East 23rd Street";
    address1 = "30 East 23rd Street";
    address2 = "";
    age = 32;
    alert = "";
    "blood_pressure_1" = "";
    "blood_pressure_2" = "";
    bmi = "";
```

I want to create a new NSDictionary that only contains a few keys from the old one, such as just `age`, `bmi`, and `alert`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [oldDict objectForKey:@"address"],  @"address",
                            [oldDict objectForKey:@"address1"], @"address1",
                            [oldDict objectForKey:@"address2"], @"address2",
                            nil];
```

You can obviously change the keys as needed...

Comment: You have a typo in the final key - address2 not address1 :)

Answer (score 9):

This might be a little easier:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"address", @"address1", @"address2", nil];
NSDictionary *subset = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
    [fullDictionary objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:@""]
    forKeys:keys];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: bigDict];
[d removeObjectsForKeys: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"address", @"age", nil]];
```

Comment: Or make an empty NSMutableDictionary and add the keys you need.

Comment: Yah, I would rather add keys than remove keys, could you give an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

Even easier

```
NSDictionary *newDictionary = [oldDictionary dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"age", @"bmi", @"alert"]];
```